Freertos stm32f4 disc board and sleep mode
I have been trying for some time to put my stm32f4 disc board in sleep mode with freertos and wake it up via an interrupt on my PB9without success. I would like my stm to go to sleep and wake up only if I have an interrupt on my pin (sleep time can be long).
After research on the internet I guess I have to use the mode tickless in FreeRTOS. Here is my FreeRTOSConfig.h
#define configUSE_TICKLESS_IDLE                  1
#define configEXPECTED_IDLE_TIME_BEFORE_SLEEP    100
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ                       ((TickType_t)1000)

My EXTI9_5_IRQHandler work fine I've tested it.
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void) {
  BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
  uint32_t current_time = HAL_GetTick();

   if (__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(STAT_ALIM_GPIO_PIN) != RESET) {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(STAT_ALIM_GPIO_PIN);
    if (current_time - last_interrupt_time > 50) {
      last_interrupt_time = current_time;

      if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, STAT_ALIM_GPIO_PIN) == GPIO_PIN_RESET) {
        vTaskNotifyGiveFromISR(T_handleStatAlimInterrupt, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
        portYIELD_FROM_ISR(xHigherPriorityTaskWoken);
      }
    }

  }
}

My Task
void User_handleStatAlimInterrupt(__unused void const *argument) {
  while (1) {
    ulTaskNotifyTake(pdTRUE, portMAX_DELAY);
    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (STAT_ALIM_GPIO_PORT, STAT_ALIM_GPIO_PIN)) {
      USER_LOG_INFO("here");
      vTaskSuspend(task1);
      vTaskSuspend(task2);


      __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
      HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);

      USER_LOG_INFO("wake");
      vTaskResume(task1);
      vTaskResume(task2);


    }else{
      USER_LOG_INFO("stat alim 0");
    }
  }
}

And for finish vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep redefinition
void vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep(TickType_t xExpectedIdleTime) {
  __disable_irq();
  __DSB();
  __ISB();

  if (eTaskConfirmSleepModeStatus() == eAbortSleep) {
    __enable_irq();
  } else {

    SysTick->CTRL &= ~SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;


    HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode(PWR_MAINREGULATOR_ON, PWR_SLEEPENTRY_WFI);


    SysTick->CTRL |= SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;

    __enable_irq();
  }
}

my problem my stm never stays in sleep mode, I can see here and immediately after wake...

find what has woken the MCU. You have many possible exception which can do this. It is basically not possible to discover remotely without having the board

Also run the program without the debug probe connected.

@0___________ Ok, do you think my Implementation is fine ?

Simon!
In the User_handleStatAlimInterrupt routine, you may try to insert the set/reset of the SysTick CTRL_ENABLE mask and the __disable_irq() / __enable_irq() around the HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode as you have done in vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep:

when the chip enters the sleep mode from the call within HAL_PWR_EnterSLEEPMode, the SysTick timer may wake up your chip.

If this doesn't solve, check for other interrupts sources, as the comments to your question suggested.
